# Add a variable to the outer closure defined by Browserify?

Tags: closures, browserify

Does Browserify provide any way to add variables to the top-most closure it generates?

I'd like to define a variable that's *not* global, but is visible to all my modules. The standard answer of "use requires(...)" doesn't work in my case because the variable's value isn't ready at the time the dependencies are processed. I really need a way to declare a variable in the closure that encompasses all my modules.

Here's a greatly simplified example of what it would look like if I *weren't* using Browserify and I had all my modules in a single file. I'm trying to figure out how to define something like myVar in the Browserify world, where I don't define the outer scope:

```
(function() {
    var myVar; <-- This is what I want in the Browserify world. Non-global, outside the individual module closure.

    var ModuleA = function() {
        function a() {
            console.log(myVar);
        };
        return { a: a };
    }();

    var ModuleB = function() {
        function b() {
            console.log(myVar);
        };
        return { b: b };
    }();

    function doItToIt() {
        // Psuedo-code... assume I'm loading myVar asynchronously.
        ajaxRequest(function(result) {
            myVar = result;
            ModuleA.a();
            ModuleB.b();
        });
    }

    doItToIt();

})();
```

Answer (score 2):

**See edit below for more in-depth on the transform method**

Sorry for being late.

There are multiple ways you could go about doing this. I am not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, because you didn't say what your code is trying to do. Here are some ways, ordered by "best option first":

1. Use a global. I know you said "Non-Global", but you didn't state why, so maybe this is still an option? When you create "var myVar;" you are not assigning a value. I assume the value is only ever assigned in "doItToIt", so why not just use a global? `(global||window)['myVar'] = result;` Just be wary of global name collisions.
2. Setup a browserify transform. Transforms work on the CONTENTS of each required file. Being as the contents of the file are dumped right inside browserify's wrappers, this is a perfect place to add your variable definition.

//compile.js

```
var fs = require('fs'),
stream = require('stream'),
browserify = require('browserify'),
b = browserify({
    basedir: './'
});

//Setup browserify transform, see NodeJS Stream transforms:
//https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform
b.transform(function(file, opts) {
    function MyTransform(opts) {
        //Create buffer array
        this.streamParts = [];

        //Call Transform constructor on this class
        stream.Transform.bind(this, opts)();
    }

    //Assign stream.Transform as parent prototype
    MyTransform.prototype = Object.create(stream.Transform.prototype);

    //Override _transform function to collect all chunks and store in our array
    MyTransform.prototype._transform = function(data, encoding, done) {
        //Store this chunk
        this.streamParts.push(data);
        done();
    };

    //On completion, merge (concat) chunks and turn into a string
    MyTransform.prototype._flush = function(done) {
        //Concat all chunks into a single buffer
        var buf = Buffer.concat(this.streamParts);

        //Turn buffer into a utf8 string
        var src = buf.toString('utf8');

        //Prefix with 'var myVar;' and push out the source body contents
        this.push('var myVar;' + src);
        done();
    };

    //Create and return our transform
    return new MyTransform();
}, {
    global: true //Warning: This will transform EVERY required file
});

//Require (and transform)
b.require('./main.js');

//Pipe to stdout... feel free to pipe to a file instead
b.bundle().pipe(process.stdout);
```

Now run via: nodejs compile.js

3. (MacOSX, Linux) Pipe the output of browserify through sed, or awk. This might fail if any other code has this exact function definition... though I doubt the other code would care if a unused variable "myVar" was declared:

`browserify main.js | sed -e 's/function(require,module,exports){/(function(require,module,exports){var myVar;/g'`

**Edit:**

In response to your comment, I made this quick and easy loader function. Wrap the browserify bundle with this anonymous function:

```
(function() {
    var resources = {}, testCallbacks = [];

    //This function loops through all "test" functions and calls
    //them. If the test function returns "true", than the callback
    //has been fired, and can be removed from the test list,
    //otherwise all resources for that callback are not ready
    //and will need to be tested again upon the load of the next
    //resource
    function fireReadyCallbacks() {
        var remainingTests = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = testCallbacks.length; i < len; i++) {
            var cb = testCallbacks[i];
            if (cb() !== true)
                remainingTests.push(cb);
        }
        testCallbacks = remainingTests;
    }

    //Our fancy require function
    function smartRequire(urls, readyCallback) {
        function insertScript(url) {
            //If resource is currently loading/loaded, just return
            if (resources[url])
                return;

            //Add to 'global' resource list
            var res = resources[url] = {
                url: url,
                loaded: false
            };

            //Insert script into page
            var scr = document.createElement('script');
            var eventName = (typeof scr.onload !== 'undefined') ? 'load' : 'readystatechange';
            scr.addEventListener(eventName, function(e) {
                //If IE says it isn't ready, return
                if (eventName === 'readystatechange' && e.readyState !== 'complete')
                    return;

                //TODO: test for error
                //Mark resource as being fully loaded
                res.loaded = true;

                //Check if any callbacks are ready to fire
                fireReadyCallbacks();
            });

            //Set async to true, and src to the url
            scr.setAttribute('async', 'true');
            scr.setAttribute('src', url);

            //Insert into document
            document.head.appendChild(scr);
        }

        //Setup a test callback and add to testCallbacks array.
        //This function calls the specified callback ONLY
        //if all resources defined have been loaded
        testCallbacks.push(function() {
            //Have all specified urls been successfully loaded?
            for (var i = 0, len = urls.length; i < len; i++) {
                var url = urls[i];
                var res = resources[url];
                if (!res || !res.loaded)
                    return false; //Nope!
            }

            //Call the callback
            readyCallback();

            //Inform fireReadyCallbacks that this callback is not needed anymore 
            return true;
        });

        //Add all resources to "resources" and insert all scripts into DOM
        for (var i = 0, len = urls.length; i < len; i++)
            insertScript(urls[i]);

        //Test if we are ready to fire callback.
        //This can happen if all resources are already loaded.
        fireReadyCallbacks();
    }

    (function(){
        /*Browserify bundle output goes here*/
    })();
})();
```

You can then setup your browserify transform to wrap your required modules like so:

```
smartRequire(['path/to/jquery','whatever/else/is/required'], function(){/*Place module output from browserify transform here*/});
```

Here is the complete code to accomplish the above:

//compile.js

```
var fs = require('fs'),
        stream = require('stream'),
        browserify = require('browserify'),
        b = browserify(['main.js'], {
            basedir: './'
        });

//Setup browserify transform, see NodeJS Stream transforms.
//https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform
b.transform(function(file, opts) {
    function MyTransform(opts) {
        //Create buffer array
        this.streamParts = [];

        //Call Transform constructor on this class
        stream.Transform.bind(this, opts)();
    }

    //Assign stream.Transform as parent prototype
    MyTransform.prototype = Object.create(stream.Transform.prototype);

    //Override _transform function to collect all chunks and store in our array
    MyTransform.prototype._transform = function(data, encoding, done) {
        //Store this chunk
        this.streamParts.push(data);
        done();
    };

    //On completion, merge (concat) chunks and turn into a string
    MyTransform.prototype._flush = function(done) {
        //Concat all chunks into a single buffer
        var buf = Buffer.concat(this.streamParts);

        //Turn buffer into a utf8 string
        var src = buf.toString('utf8');

        //Wrap with our smartRequire... change resources as needed, can even
        //place resources into a variable
        this.push('smartRequire(["http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"],function(){' + src + '});');
        done();
    };

    //Create and return our transform
    return new MyTransform();
}, {
    global: true //Warning: This will transform EVERY required file
});

var outFile = 'bundle.js';
console.log('Writing ' + outFile + '...');

var outputStream = fs.createWriteStream(outFile, {
    flags: 'w',
    encoding: 'utf8'
});

//Get the output stream from browserify
var dataStream = b.bundle(), firstChunk = true;

//Our smart require blob... minified for sanity's sake
var prefixBlob='function fireReadyCallbacks(){for(var c=[],e=0,f=testCallbacks.length;e<f;e++){var a=testCallbacks[e];!0!==a()&&c.push(a)}testCallbacks=c}function smartRequire(c,e){function f(b){if(!resources[b]){var c=resources[b]={url:b,loaded:!1},d=document.createElement("script"),a="undefined"!==typeof d.onload?"load":"readystatechange";d.addEventListener(a,function(b){if("readystatechange"!==a||"complete"===b.readyState)c.loaded=!0,fireReadyCallbacks()});d.setAttribute("async","true");d.setAttribute("src",b);document.head.appendChild(d)}}testCallbacks.push(function(){for(var b=0,a=c.length;b<a;b++){var d=resources[c[b]];if(!d||!d.loaded)return!1}e();return!0});for(var a=0,g=c.length;a<g;a++)f(c[a]);fireReadyCallbacks()};var resources={},testCallbacks=[];';

//Intercept the stream, and inject our prefix code
//before the first chunk
dataStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    if (firstChunk) {
        outputStream.write('(function(){' + prefixBlob);
        outputStream.write(chunk);
        firstChunk = false
    } else {
        outputStream.write(chunk);
    }
});
dataStream.on('end', function(chunk) {
    //Add end of closure wrapper
    outputStream.end((chunk) ? (chunk.toString('utf8') + '})();') : '})();');
});
dataStream.on('error', function(file, err) {
    console.log('Error: ', file, err);
});

outputStream.on('finish', function() {
    outputStream.close();
    console.log('Compiled Success!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll look into transforms. I'm writing a bit of Javascript that gets loaded into third-party sites, which is why I'm refraining from the use of any global variables. Because I'm getting loaded on a 3rd party site, I also asynchronously load my own version of jQuery with noConflict and it's this version of jQuery that I want to make accessible to all my modules. The real nitty gritty question about my specific situation are written up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441185/how-to-use-my-own-version-of-jquery-with-browserified-modules